# How to grab the value of website using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

[image: https]

I am writing code in `JAVA` by using selenium to automate a website. I am trying grab the value in the picture attached, `40 images`. I'm just trying to get the value `40`.

HTML

```
<div class="group-right">
   <h1 class="ng-binding">Night Life Of China</h1>
   <ul class="stats">
      <li class="stats-list">
         <span>
             <span class="stats-list__value ng-binding">40</span> images
         </span>
      </li>
```

Can anyone help?

This is what I've done, (super wrong)

```
       WebElement imgcount = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span:first-child"));
        imgcount.getAttribute("value");
       // System.out.println("No. of Images Displayed: " + value());

    if (listImages.size() == imgcount.getText()) {
        System.out.println("Image and Count Match");
        System.out.println("listImages: " + listImages.size());
        System.out.println("Number of Images says:" + imgcount.getText());
    } else {
        System.out.println("IMAGES DO NOT MATCH! Closing Browser Now!");
        System.out.println("Number of Images says:" + imgcount.getText());
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so we can make suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your provided `cssSelector` locator locats parent `span`  element that's why you are getting whole text. You just need to locate `span` with class `stats-list__value` as below :-

```
WebElement imgcount = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.stats-list__value"));
System.out.println("Number of Images says:" + imgcount.getText());
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! thanks, still new to using cssSelectors and how to use it in different ways. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You can learn more about `cssSelector` from here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp